# Sobolev embedding with $n>kp$ implies $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)\subset L^q(\mathbb R^n)$ continuously for all $p\leq q\leq \infty$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations

I want to prove that  $n>kp$ implies $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)\subset L^q(\mathbb R^n)$ continuously for all $p\leq q\leq \infty$.

Idea of proof:

According to Wikipedia, if $n>kp$ then $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)\subset C^{r,\alpha}(\mathbb R^n)$ for some $\alpha,r$ such that $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{k}{n}=-\frac{r+\alpha}{n}$ with $\alpha\in (0,1)$.

Can we say that if $f\in W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)\subset C^{r,\alpha}(\mathbb R^n)$ then $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$? That is, do we have $\lVert f\rVert_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}\leq c\lVert f\rVert_{C^{r,\alpha}(\mathbb R^n)}$ for some $c>0$?

Then we could apply Holder's inequality to prove that $\lVert f\rVert_{L^q(\mathbb R^n)}\leq \lVert f\rVert^\theta_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}\lVert f\rVert_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}^{1-\theta}\leq C\lVert f\rVert_{W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)}^\theta c\lVert f\rVert_{C^{r,\alpha}(\mathbb R^n)}^{1-\theta}\leq cC\lVert f\rVert_{W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

**The embedding you are looking for does NOT hold for the full range of parameters $q$.**

In [your recent question on the case $n = kp$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689722/critical-case-of-sobolev-embedding-do-we-have-w1-p-mathbb-rn-subset-lq?rq=1), I had given you a reference (Demengel's book) which states and proves all cases in Theorem 2.31, including the case of this new question for $n > kp$. I encourage you to read it again.

When $n>kp$, the embedding $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is only true for $p \leq q \leq \frac{np}{n-kp}$. For example, with $n = 2$, $k = 1$, $p = 1$, you only have $W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^2) \hookrightarrow L^q(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for $1 \leq q \leq 2$, but not above. This is easily seen by scaling arguments (considering functions of the form $f(\lambda x)$ for a family of $\lambda \to 0$ or $\lambda \to \infty$). You can read Remark 2.34 in the same reference which explains this more thoroughly.